# How to feed a variable into a zenity --text-info box?

Tags: bash, zenity

For some reason the zenity --text box won't display the text string.  Likely because it is too long.  I'm hoping a --text-info box will do the trick.

Is there anyway to get the --filename= param to take a string input rather than a file input?

Example:

```
help_zenity_output(){
    zenity --text-info --width 777 --title 'Hotstrings -> Command' \
    --filename=<<<"$1"
    #--text="$1"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use the `--filename` parameter. Just drop it. Zenity reads the content from `stdin`.

```sh
help_zenity_output(){
  zenity --text-info --width 777 --title 'Hotstrings -> Command' <<< "$1"
}
```